# Two-Lock Concurrent Queue Algorithm Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, locking

So I was going over the article [Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking Concurrent Queue Algorithms](https://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/podc-1996.pdf) by Maged M. Michael and Michael L. Scott, and there is a small issue I don't get:

[image]

Lets say we have two concurrent threads that are fired right after the queue is initialized. One of the threads calls `enqueue` and the other calls `dequeue`. What prevents them from accessing the `next` field of the dummy node both at the same time? can't the `dequeue` thread read the `next` field while the `enqueue` thread write to it? They both use different locks... so I dont understand what synchronizes between them..

Thanks.

Comment: Which dummy node are you referring to?

Comment: the one that is created at initialize()

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to the first node that's created in initialize?

Comment: yes, that's the one i'm referring to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enqueue() only manipulates the tail, and dequeue() only manipulates the head, so they don't need to use the same locks.  There is a special case when head and tail point to the same node, the "dummy" node that was created in initialize. And you're correct that enqueue() could be writing to that node's next pointer while dequeue() is trying to read it.

There is no issue with that concurrent read and write.  Notice that enqueue() creates a new node, and fully initializes that object, before making it visible to by writing it to tail->next.  Therefore, no other code can ever see this new node in a halfway initialized state.  Furthermore, reads/writes to a pointer are atomic, so it's not possible for dequeue() to get, say, half of the pointer.

So in your scenario where enqueue() and dequeue() are both called right away, there are two possibilities:

- enqueue() writes to tail->next before dequeue() reads from head->next.  In this case, dequeue() will see the node that was enqueued and will return it.
- dequeue() reads from head->next before enqueue() writes to tail->next.  In this case, dequeue() thinks the queue is empty and returns false.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that reads/writes to pointers are atomic.

Comment: So I guess that the correctness of this algorithm is implementation dependent. Because as I read now, it is not truly guaranteed in C++ for example, that pointer manipulation is atomic.

Comment: Right, it seems that in C++ you'd want to use atomic pointers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic.  It definitely does depend on the memory model of the language you're using.